# HTML contact form wont send

Tags: html, web, contact-form

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
   <title>Contact</title>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <link href="CSS/contact.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <form class="contact-form" action="mailto:zachareaislam@gmail.com" method="post">
       <br><br>
       <input type="text" name="first_Name" placeholder="First name" pattern="[a-z, A-Z]{0,15}" required><br>
       <input type="text" name="last_Name" placeholder="Last Name" pattern="[a-z, A-Z]{0,15}" required><br>
       <input type="email" name="email " placeholder="Your email address" required><br>
       <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject"><br>
       <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your message" required></textarea><br>
       <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
   </div>
  </main>
 </body>
</html>
```

/*Not sure as to why it doesn't work.
/*Only just noticed it didn't work while performing some maintenance

Comment: Simple Html Form wont send any mail,You have to add any script [Javascript / Php Script] to process your data and send you mail

Answer (score 0):

You cannot only use HTML, since sending data with a form requires a server backend (like with node or php) to post data.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send a form directly to email from the HTML. Form should be submitted to some processing file, like .php. You might have had some kind of framework that used to process these types of forms, but generally it should be following:

1. Action should be a path to the script file like mail.php
2. Mail.php receives info from the HTML in a $_REQUEST[] set of variables, each variable has a "name" and value.
3. It processes the request, then can send back to the page.